# How to add ViewpagerIndicator 2.3.1 and ActionBarSherlock 4.1 in a project

Tags: android

I want to use both VPI and ABS in my project. But I can't include them into my project. I tried delete android-support-v4 at two library but it doesn't work.

Thanks for advice!

```
<Tab>[2012-07-20 01:37:24 - SHopping] C:\Users\KIENVITHANH\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\res\values\vpi__attrs.xml:21: error: Attribute "vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle" has already been defined
[2012-07-20 01:37:24 - SHopping] C:\Users\KIENVITHANH\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\res\values\vpi__attrs.xml:23: error: Attribute "vpiLinePageIndicatorStyle" has already been defined
[2012-07-20 01:37:24 - SHopping] C:\Users\KIENVITHANH\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\res\values\vpi__attrs.xml:25: error: Attribute "vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle" has already been defined
</Tab>
```

Comment: "I tried delete android-support-v4 at two library but it doesn't work." Huh?

Answer (score 0):

Merge them together in your own style like:

```
 <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.CirclePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TitlePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
```

with ABS as a parent and then use that theme in your manifest.

Comment: Mode: How to merge them together?

Answer (score 0):

[How to Add Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) 
And  [Reading this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html) wont do any harm either

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete the android-support-v4 from the lib folder of ViewPagerIndicator, and copy the android-support-v4 from ActionBarSherlock into the lib folder of ViewPagerIndicator